# AngularJS child $http.post from template ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my AngularJS application I get data with an $http.post (I'm using a json rpc API) on my controller and then I render this data (an array of items) with a

```
<div ng-repeat="item in arrayItems">
    {{ makeANewHttpRequest(item.relatedItemId).propertyName }}
</div>
```

What I need is to implement $scope.makeANewHttpRequest(itemId) function that it's call as many time as arrayItems.length and return the relatedItem objects from a new $http.post request.

How can I do that?
Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create one factory that will responsible for `$http.post` call which has been exposed to other, and it will return promise object. You can call that service method by adding `dataService` factory as reference on controller dependency. Controller will call the service function like `dataService.getData(url, data)` & on each promise resolved it will increament counter, update the data and then call the next post if `arrayItems` count doesn't exceeds by counter.

**Factory**

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.factory('dataService', function($http) {
    var getData = function(url, data) {
        return $http.post(url, {
            data
        }).then(function(res) {
            return res.data;
        });
    };

    return {
        getData: getData
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
myModule.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
    //other code
    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.makeANewHttpRequest = function(id) {
        dataService.getData(url+id, data).then(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data; //updated the data each time when response received
            ++$scope.counter; //increment counter
            if ($scope.counter >= $scope.arrayItems.length) //check counter should not exceed limit
                $scope.makeANewHttpRequest(id);
        });
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
ng-click="counter=0;$scope.makeANewHttpRequest(id)" //clear count and call method
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: @Fabrizio A do you required anything more from me?

Comment: Hi, sorry for my delay. I'm relative new to Angular and I've read about $q object. Right now I've solved my problem with a different use of API ... but your solutions seems be elegant and I'm studying it for another similar question. I need to create my first service to obtain an array of object (with an $http.post) and return it to my control to populate a ngTable. Since all services in angular are singleton, I would love to cache the retrieved data for a future refresh of the same controller.

Comment: @FabrizioA  can you share whatever you tried..& do you required my help on it?

Comment: you may take a look here ;) Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963955/create-angularjs-cached-service-for-http-post-request

Answer (score 1):

First, I think the right way would be to just generate all the data needed in the server when you do your first http request. This will save you all the extra post requests you have to do for each item in the array. If you must do it this way, then the correct way is to handle the call to makeANewHttpRequest in the controller once you get the data back.

```
$http.post('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   //do the new http requests here
   var promiseArr = []
   angular.forEach(data, function(val) {
     promiseArr.push(makeANewHttpRequest(val));
   });
   $q.all(promiseArr).then(function(updatedValues) {
       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           data[i].relatedItemId = updatedValues[i];
       }
       $scope.arrayItems = data;
   });
});

function makeANewHttpRequest(item) {
    return $http.post('/someUrl', item.relatedItemId);
}
```

Comment: where did you maintained promises and udpation of scope variables?

Comment: Updated the above to be less vague. Also made use of $q.all so that arrayItems will only be assigned after all the data needed is available.